# Converting pImpl pointer back to caller type

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I am using pimpl idiom in my program and I am stuck in one place. My code is

```
Class*
Class::GetP()
{
return ClassImpl->GetP();
}
```

In my ClassImpl->GetP() I have

```
ClassImpl*
ClassImpl::GetP()
{
return pClassImpl;
}
```

As you can see I need to convert my pImpl bact to my caller type.
What is the way?

I dont want to use any casting
Please advice

Comment: What is the reason of not wanting to use any casting?

Comment: What is `GetP` supposed to be doing? Why do you need it?

Comment: GetP actually returns a new instancde of some type which is made based on a parameter passed to getP, also i can use reintepret cast but it has some overheads.
I think solution is simple and I am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you simply do

```
Class *
Class::GetP()
{
    return this;
}
```

since callers of `Class::GetP()` shouldn't have a pointer to the internals anyway? (But then, what is that method for? It doesn't give the caller anything that they don't already have.)

Comment: actually its more like GetP(some param)
it returns a new instance which is constructed in impl class using this parameter

Comment: If it's returning a new instance, you should be creating a `new Class` somehow and returning that. So your implementation function would be `Class *ClassImpl::GetP(...) { ... }` (note the return type changed from `ClassImpl *` to `Class *`).

Comment: so it it ok to create the instance of my caller in my pImpl class?

Comment: The problem is the `GetP` function will have a lot of `ClassImpl->mem1`, `ClassImpl->mem2`, `ClassImpl->mem3`, which is quite messy hence the motivation to create a `GetP` in `ClassImpl`, but then we run into the problem of "convert pimpl back caller type". Is there a way to make it work by using OP's approach?